# Monte Carlo and function minimization (simulated annealing)

Tags: sampling, optimization, monte-carlo

I posted this question on math.stackexchange, but did not get an answer and a limited amount of views, so I removed the question there and post it here.

Recently I was asking myself some basic questions about the usage of Monte Carlo for function minimization.

Suppose we have a finite set $I$ and a function $E :I\rightarrow R$. We want to minimize $E$. $I$ is finite, but quite large, therefore direct minimization is not possible.

**Observation 1**:: If we fix a probability density funtion $p(i)$ over $I$ we can sample $p(i)$ via Metropolis. All we need is a transition matrix $T(i|j)$ with some mild properties.

How can we use Obs. $1$? If we engineer some parametric distributions $p_a(i)$ such that:

$\lim_{a \rightarrow0} \frac{p_a(i)}{p_a(j)}=+\infty$, if $E(i)<E(j)$

( and equal to $1$ if $E(i)=E(j)$)

than we can start from a finite $a$, some initial conditions, and letting it go to $0$, so that it settles to a local minimum. This is simulated annealing I think. (possible choice: $p_a(i) \sim e^{-E(i)/a}$)

Now my question is:

**QUESTION:** when does it make sense to use such a methodology to find a minimum ? E.g. when other procedures would be better ?

Some thoughts:

- Suppose that $E$ is a random function that has no "structure" (whatever it means). Than such a procedure would not be more efficient I guess than just random sampling and picking the minimum after $N$ trials ;
- Since it looks that without any structure of $I$ random sampling is as efficient as simulated annealing  I guess that the transition matrix $T$ should be tailored to follow some properties of $I$ (or better of the energy landscape given by $E$) ? Is this correct ? Are there guidelines on this point?

Comment: The finiteness of $I$ is going to cause you problems.   More generally, you might want to look up stochastic approximation (https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/) as well as simulated annealing...  Having written that, though, this really is off topic for a statistics site.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. What type of issues it should bring? Are you referring to SA in particular?

Comment: There's nothing really statistical here, this is about optimization instead.  Sure, there's a probability distribution for your proposals in there somewhere, but the question is about optimization, not statistics as such.

Comment: Yes that I understand. You may vote to close the question and there is the option to suggest a site where to migrate the question. Anyway I was asking about clarifications about your statement ok the finitness of the set.

Comment: Well, if it's finite and convex, even $||E|| = 10^6$ can be solved via interval halving in 20 or so steps, and there are faster methods.  If it's finite that brings the possibility of it being unordered (your no "structure", in effect), in which case an exhaustive search is all you have.  The structure of $E$ has a big influence on what you would do.

Comment: Great thanks for confirming. Exactly I was asking for guidelines about the "structure"->"action" relationship in this setting, even just specializing to the simulated annealing approach. But maybe my question is simply too broad to be answered, it has happened to me also in the past ...

Comment: Simulated annealing is best used if you have a nonconvex function that still has a lot of structure to it, essentially having a meaningful discrete derivative that doesn't vary too quickly, like a discretized version of $sin(x) - 0.1x$ over the interval $[-6,6]$; a couple of local minima, one of which you'd like a chance to escape from.